# Cross-thread operation not valid in C#?

Tags: c#

I am creating a background worker thread and Loading data in it and showing in UI.
I know the problem is while showing the data in UI(because it is a UI thread)
But i get the data from server in form of blocks .
Suppose for the first time receive 10 records then i have to update the Ui and then call the next records.

How to resolve this Issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: Issue is when i call UpdateUserUI() method it gives error "Cross thread operation not valid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `BackgroundWorker` you have to make use of the report progress feature.

What I usually do is to do the work required inside the DoWork method, and when you want to update the GUI, call `worker.ReportProgress` with the needed data. Then in the report progress method, update the GUI since that method will be run on the GUI thread. Also make sure you set `WorkerReportsProgress` to true, else you will get an exception when trying to call `ReportProgress`.

Comment: But my requirement is get some n records(say 10) update the UI then call another records then update the UI.When i call updateUI after 10 records it gives Cross thread Exception.

Comment: That is my point. In `DoWork`, get 10 records, then call `ReportProgress` and update the GUI, in `DoWork` get 10 more records, and call `ReportProgress` again. Continue until all records are read.

Comment: If you are not going to show a progress bar you can send it as 0 since you wont use it. The second parameter accept an object, and here you can send your actual data.